# Translation of the word "describe/ description"

Tags: translation, words

Each time, when I need to translate the word "to describe" or "descrtiption", in sentences like:

> "**Describe** the work position."

or

> "The **description** of the company's present state of affairs."

I get confused. Till now I could not manage to find any better way of translating than using the word **説明する** for verb or **説明【せつめい】**　for a noun.
Last time I also started to use **述べる【のべる】** for the meaning of the verb "to describe".
But I am not sure, that it is that very right way...Even maybe being not the worst.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single word that can cover all the meanings of "describe".

- 説明する: To explain something (logically) using many words so that people can understand it.
- 述べる: Mostly interchangeable with 説明する, but basically it just means "to state". You can say 事件を説明する but not 事件を述べる. Despite its appearance, this is a fairly stiff word, and 述べてください/述べろ would sound like as if I were taking an examination. Unless there is an example sentence and a context, I can't tell whether your use of 述べる is acceptable or not.
- 表現する, 表す: To express something (aesthetically or figuratively) using a picture, poem, etc. (i.e., "this picture describes the man's internal ...")